# undefined local variable or method `days_till_expired'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently I have a method called `days_till_expired` defined in my `subscriber` model. I'm trying to call it in the controller but it doesn't seem to be working? I must be missing something obvious because this should be a simple implementation. I'll post my code for clarity.

MODEL METHOD:

```
 def days_till_expired
  ((created_at + 1.year) - DateTime.now).to_i / 1.day
 end
```

CONTROLLER:

```
 def visit
   @subscriber = Subscriber.find_by_phone_number(params[:phone_number])
 if @subscriber
   @subscriber.visit =+ 1
   @subscriber.save
   flash[:notice] = "Thank You! You have #{days_till_expired} until renewal"
   redirect_to subscribers_search_path(:subscriber)
 else
  render "search"
 end
end
```

As you can see I'm simple trying to call the method with interpolation inside the flash notice but I keep getting this ERROR:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling to the methods, if you have days_till_expired on your model you forgot to use your model @subscriber.days_till_expired

```
flash[:notice] = "Thank You! You have #{@subscriber.days_till_expired} until renewal"
```

If I were you, I would try to move that counter logic to the model.